# flex open source sdk compile error of samples on linux

Tags: linux, apache-flex, compilation

I downloaded lastest version of [flex open source sdk](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/download?build=3.4.1.10084&pkgtype=2). I wanted to compile some samples specifically explorer example. At first build.sh gave me weird error and with little search I nailed it by converting all bash files and mxml files with dos2unix. It is file type error. However now I get this error

```
./build.sh
Error: Could not resolve <mx:Script> to a component implementation.  <mx:Script>
```

When I execute build.sh, some of the samples give this weird error. I searched this error on the net, their solution is to add `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US` as jre parameters. However, this solution is for Turkish Windows XP.

My system is [Pardus](http://www.pardus.org.tr), yet another linux distribution.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the best answer, but I think the standard practice is to use ANT (or something similar) for a command line build environment. This is how Adobe builds the framework at least, so you may have a bit better luck that way.

Here is a good primer: http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/01/07/using-ant-to-build-an-application/

Once you have a build.xml file, you can build the project in any environment with a simple ``ant build`` command.